# Eliminar efectos visuales que generan los navegadores al autocompletar formulario

Tags: formularios, navegador-web

Mi pregunta es si es posible eliminar de alguna manera los efectos visuales que generan de manera automática  los navegadores cuando auntocompletas con datos guardados de usuario, contraseña etc...
Cuando elijo completar los campos con datos de contraseña y usuario guardados, me cambia los colores del background de los campos y no queda nada bien con el resto de estilos de mi página.
Saludos y grácias.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay algunas opciones que podrías considerar:

Autocompletar personalizado: En lugar de confiar en el autocompletado automático del navegador, podrías implementar tu propio autocompletado personalizado utilizando HTML, CSS y JavaScript. Esto te daría un control total sobre el aspecto visual de los campos y cómo se completan.
Estilos personalizados para autocompletado: Algunos navegadores permiten personalizar los estilos de los campos autocompletados utilizando pseudoclases CSS como :-webkit-autofill, :-webkit-autofill:hover y :-webkit-autofill:focus. Sin embargo, estos estilos solo funcionan en navegadores basados en WebKit (como Chrome y Safari) y podrían cambiar en futuras versiones. Ejemplo:

```
input:-webkit-autofill { background-color: #f4f4f4; }
```

Atributos de autocompletado: Puedes utilizar los atributos autocomplete en los campos del formulario para indicar al navegador que no debe autocompletar ciertos campos. Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

El valor off en el atributo autocomplete indica al navegador que no debe autocompletar el campo, mientras que new-password es una sugerencia para campos de contraseña en los navegadores modernos.

JS para desactivar autocompletado: Puedes utilizar JavaScript para desactivar el autocompletado en los campos de formulario. Aquí hay un ejemplo usando jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

Es importante destacar que estas opciones pueden tener efectos diferentes en diferentes navegadores y versiones. Por lo tanto, te recomiendo realizar pruebas en diferentes navegadores para asegurarte de que los cambios se comporten como deseas en cada uno.